# Responsive header width two overlapping images

Tags: javascript, html, css, header

I am creating a responsive header with two overlapping images. A div can be larger or smaller, based on the current mouse position. The problem is to create this header responsive. The center of both images should be in the center of the webpage. This is hard to achieve as the div's that contain the images are not in the center of the document. You can see my current progress [here](http://www.pvdlmultimedia.nl/searching/). Whenever the browser is around 1200 pixels it looks fine (the image width is 1280 px). However, when i resize the browser to a smaller size the effect is not how it is meant to be.

HTML

```
<div class="header">
<div class="headerleft"><img src="images/rick.png" width="1280" height="200" id="rick" alt="rick" align="middle"></div>
<div class="headerright"><img src="images/peter.png" width="1280" height="200" id="peter" alt="peter" align="right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    .header{
        height: 200px;
        width: 100%;
        background-size: 50%;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    .headerleft{
        background-color: red;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow:hidden;
        background-image: url('images/rick.png');
        background-position: left;
    }

    .headerright{
        background-color: blue;
        width: 50%;
        height: 100%;
        float: right;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow:hidden;
        /*background-image: url('images/peter.png');*/
        background-position: right;
    }
```

Javascript

```
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e){
    page = $( document ).width();
    pagecrop = page/2;  
    $('.headerright').css({
       width:  e.pageX/2+pagecrop/2,
    });
    });

    $(document).on('mousemove', function(e){
    page = $( document ).width();
    pagecrop = page/2;
    $('.headerleft').css({
       width:  pagecrop-e.pageX/2+pagecrop/2,
    });
    });
```

Comment: Hey that is a cool effect! What does it look like without any JS in use at all? Have you considered using CSS3 Transform?

Comment: Thanks! it does need the JS, as it responds to the cursor position. I have not considered CSS3 Transform, as i don't think it can solve the problem. I did try to put both image as background in css. But couldn't solve it either.

Comment: I was thinking something like this: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/  or this: http://css-tricks.com/centering-percentage-widthheight-elements/ - then maybe use a little js to change the transform property instead of the width.

Comment: did not manage to make it properly :(

Comment: I really would go "back to square one" on this and change the approach.  If I get time I'll create a Proof of Concept for you.

Comment: i'm getting close but did not manage to fix the Jquery

Comment: transform: translate(0%); is the right property. However i can not set it with jquery.

Comment: var $winwidth = $(window).width();
  $('#peter').css({
  'transform':'translate'($winwidth + 'px')}); is not changing anything to the property

Comment: I think you can actually just use the :hover pseudo element and change using (calc) - not 100% on this, but I'll see if I can get something working for you :D

Comment: got it working! thank you very much. I'll post the code.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working with the CSS transform translate property, and change that value with jquery. Thank you docodemore!

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var $winwidth = $(window).width();
    var width2 = 1280-$winwidth
    var width3 = width2/2
        $('#peter').css('transform', 'translate(' + width3  + 'px)');
        $('#rick').css('transform', 'translate(-' + width3  + 'px)');
    $(window).bind("resize", function(){ 
        var $winwidth = $(window).width();
        var width2 = 1280-$winwidth
        var width3 = width2/2
            $('#peter').css('transform', 'translate(' + width3 + 'px)');
            $('#rick').css('transform', 'translate(-' + width3  + 'px)');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the fixed pixel size of the images in the HTML and replacing with CSS or changing the 1280px value to 100% as such:

```
<div class="header">
<div class="headerleft"><img src="images/rick.png" width="100%" height="200" id="rick" alt="rick"  align="middle"></div>
<div class="headerright"><img src="images/peter.png" width="100%" height="200" id="peter" alt="peter" align="right"></div>
</div>
```

Not sure if that's the desired effect you're after but worth a shot perhaps?